# Checking and enforcing downstream Z constraint for synthetic streams?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, lidar, elevation, taudem

Assume I've delineated planar (X, Y) stream breaklines to use them for enforcement of bare ground DEM derivation from high density lidar data. The stream features are in a Z and M enabled polyline shapefile. To convert them into 3D breaklines I use a conflation process to populate the Z from an interpolation of nearby ground points in the same lidar. Before using them for hydro enforcement in DEM derivation, one needs to see that the vertex elevations decrease monotonically in the downstream direction -due to ground noise in the lidar this is not always the case. Does anybody know of a (python, standalone, QGIS or other OS) tool/code to:

- Check for downstream elevation monotonic decrease? The tool would detect, maybe tag by ID/measure, polyline segments where the stream deviates from strict downstream gradient. An illustration:
  [image: Unenforced stream elevation profile]
- Enforce the downstream Z monotonicity when errors are found. After enforcement the stream above would look like:"

[image: Stream after monotonicity enforcement]